# use alternate namespace for the soapenv

Tags: wcf, namespaces

Our company thinks it is using valid SOAP. However, they are using this namespace declaration for the soapenv namespace prefix:

```
xmlns:cfg-env="http://www.co.com/schemas/cfg-env/"
```

This manifests itself in the xml/soap request message like this:

```
<cfg-env:Envelope xmlns="http://www.co.com/schemas/CFX/" xmlns:cfg-           env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cfg-hdr="http://www.co.com/schemas/cfg-hdr/">
<cfg-env:Header>
```

This soap namespace declaration is not being recognized by WCF out of the box. When I change that to the proper soap 1.1 namespace WCF recognizes the request and begins to process the message.

Here is the proper declaration we are all familiar with:
xmlns:cfg-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

When I use this namespace declaration for the typical soapenv prefix which here is cfg-env WCF recognizes the request message.

Is there a way to change WCF to recognize this incorrect soapenv namespace declaration so my messages will be recognized without modification?

Given this as a requirement I'll have to change the request messages cfg-env namespace declaration. It would be helpful for me to leave the request messages in tact with no changes in order for this to work.

Can an alternate namespace declaration be applied in WCF, and how, to accommodate for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. What your company is producing is simply not SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is not a configuration.

Take a look at this article:

http://vanacosmin.ro/Articles/Read/WCFEnvelopeNamespacePrefix

Here you can find how to do this on the server side, but if you use ApplyClientBehavior instead of ApplyDispatchBehavior you can configure the same MessageFormatter to run on your WCF client application.